# How can I search for any meta tag where name starts with "ABC_" or "XYZ_" using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple `<meta>` html tags. I need to use jQuery to get all the meta tags where name starts with "ABC_" or "XYZ_" then loop through them.

Here is what I have done.

```
var tags = $( "meta[name^='ABC_']" );

$.each(tags, function(index, tag){
   //print the value of each tag
   console.log( $(tag).attr('value') );
});
```

The only problem is that I need to also search for any name that starts with  "ABC_" or "XYZ_" not just "ABC_"

How can I add "XYZ_" to the mix

Comment: meta[name^='ABC_'],meta[name^='XYZ_']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine multiple selectors in a single selector by connecting them with comma.

```
$( "meta[name^='ABC_'], meta[name^='XYZ_']" )
```

This will return elements that match either selector.